# Returning impl Iterator with multiple types of iterator

Tags: function, rust, iterator

I've tried to distill my problem into a minimal example. In the function below, if I just have either branch of the if statement, the program compiles just fine.

```rust
fn foo(bar: bool) -> impl Iterator<Item = u32> {
    if bar {
        vec![].into_iter()
    } else {
        vec![].into_iter().map(|o| o)
    }
}
```

However, having both branches together as I've written above gives the following error:

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
2 | /     if bar {
3 | |         vec![].into_iter()
  | |         ------------------ expected because of this
4 | |     } else {
5 | |         vec![].into_iter().map(|o| o)
  | |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::vec::IntoIter`, found struct `Map`
6 | |     }
  | |_____- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
  |
  = note: expected struct `std::vec::IntoIter<_>`
             found struct `Map<std::vec::IntoIter<_>, [closure@src/main.rs:5:32: 5:37]>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

By my understanding, the problem is that even though the declared return type is `impl Iterator`, the compiler must pick a concrete type to use. While both branches of the if statement produce a value which is of type `impl Iterator`, they are different concrete types. However, I don't know what concrete type I can use to resolve this problem.

Comment: Since you have an iterator type in both arms, you may want to `collect` them into a `Vec`, unless you really have a need for an iterator afterwards.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows I was about to edit my question to note that I'm aware `collect` is a solution, but the resulting vector in my actual program is too large to materialize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. `impl` isn't a magic catch-all solution that can hide an implementation permanently. It's just convenient syntax so that *you*, the programmer, don't have to think about the return type. But there still must exist *one* unique return type.

Now, you *could* (I don't recommend this) write an `enum` which can be either of the two iterator types.

```
// Pseudocode, I'm not looking up the actual types because they're complicated
enum MyIterator {
  IsVectorIterator(Vec::Iter<u32>),
  IsMapIterator(iter::Map<Vec::Iter<u32>, u32, ...>),
}
```

and then you *could* write an `Iterator` implementation for this type that delegates to whatever is inside. That's a lot of work and a lot of boilerplate, when trait objects will do it for us.

I recommend that you return `Box<dyn Iterator<Item=u32>>` from your function.

```
fn foo(bar: bool) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u32>> {
  if bar {
    Box::new(vec![].into_iter())
  } else {
    Box::new(vec![].into_iter().map(|o| o))
  }
}
```

This is a dynamic trait object, so it's entirely acceptable that we don't know the concrete type until runtime. It does require dynamic dispatch (since the trait object has to *remember* how to be iterated over), but it's a very cheap cost to pay in exchange for not having to mess with the types explicitly.

Note that, depending on who owns the input vector (in your example, it's a temporary `vec![]`, but I imagine in your real code that it's an argument with a lifetime), your `dyn` may have to have a lifetime argument, like

```
Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a>
```

where `'a` is the lifetime of the input vector.

Comment: Another option is `Either`

Comment: @PitaJ Fair point although in my real application, there are more than two possibilities.

Comment: Thank you! I'm used to languages with autoboxing, so I didn't really think about this, but it's obvious in retrospect.